# Renaming files with inode number [UNIX]

Tags: unix, rename, linode

I'm simply trying to rename a file by attaching an underscore and the inode number of said file before I move it to a directory.

The description is:

> To avoid name conflicts in the recycle bin, change the file name to
>   the original name followed by an underscore, followed by the inode for
>   the file.  For example, if a file named "f1" with inode 1234 were
>   removed, the file would be named f1_1234 in the recycle bin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy if *parallel* is available :

```
ls f* | parallel 'mv {} newDir/{}_`stat -c%i {}`'
```