# Copy specific files from subdirectories into one directory

Tags: bash, file, copy, zsh, file-copying

I have a directory:

```
❯ find ./images -name *150x150.jpg
./images/2060511653921052666.images/thumb-150x150.jpg
./images/1777759401031970571.images/thumb-150x150.jpg
./images/1901716489977597520.images/thumb-150x150.jpg
./images/2008758225324557620.images/thumb-150x150.jpg
./images/1988762968386208381.images/thumb-150x150.jpg
./images/1802341648716075239.images/thumb-150x150.jpg
./images/2051017760380879322.images/thumb-150x150.jpg
./images/1974813836146304123.images/thumb-150x150.jpg
./images/2003120002653201215.images/thumb-150x150.jpg
./images/1911925394312129508.images/thumb-150x150.jpg
(...)
```

I would like to copy all those files (`thumb-150x150.jpg`) into one directory.

```
❯ find ./images -name *150x150.jpg -exec cp {} ./another-directory \;
```

But of course every file will be overwritten by the next one.

So how could I copy them to either:

1) `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `3.jpg`... etc

or

2) use the subdirectory id (./images/**2060511653921052666**.images/thumb-150x150.jpg) as the target filename (`2060511653921052666.jpg` in this example) ?

Comment: each file will obviously need a new/distinct name; while the SO community can come up with a lengthy list of new names/formats, ultimately the format of the new name is up to you to decide; how do you plan to reference/use these files in the future? will you need to apply any type of ordering to the new file names? do you need an ability to search-for/list the files based on a specific pattern? should the new file name contain any info to state where it originally came from? does the file need to relate-to/reference some other directory or file?

Comment: File name has to be distinct - thats all. I wont need to reference to a particular file. I just need all of them in one place (folder).

Comment: @gib : Why not naming the files simply, i.e., `2060511653921052666-thumb-150x150.jpg`. You can then put all of them into the same directory and still see where they come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use loop:

```
i=1
find ./images -name *150x150.jpg | while read line; do
        cp $line /anotherdir/$i.jpg
        i=$[i+1]
done
```

Comment: Replace `i=$[i+1]` with `((i++))`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple bash script, using `$RANDOM` to generate a random number for each image copied. A random number is embedded in the new name of each file.

Note that `$RANDOM` generates a random number between 1 and 32767. So the same random number could be produced more than once. This is only likely if you had tens of thousand images to copy.

It is fairly easy to improve the randomness of each number generated is necessary.

```
# !/bin/bash
cd images
for d in *
do
    [ -d $d ] && cd $d
    for image in *150x150.jpg
    do
        cp -pv $image /another-dir/thumb${RANDOM}.jpg
    done
    [ -d $d ] && cd ..
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have GNU parallel it's possible:

```
find ./images -name *150x150.jpg | \
parallel 'mv {} ./another-directory/`stat -c%i {}`_{/}'
```

the `stat -c%i {}` get's the inode for each file

I tested the command bellow on my system:

```
find -iname "*.mp3" | parallel 'cp {} ~/tmp/{/.}_`stat -c%i {}`.mp3'

{/} .......... gets just the filename with no full path "basename"
{.} .......... removes extension
```

Before runing the actual command you can put a `echo` command in front of cp or mv in order to test your command.

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16074963/2571881